# `numpy.nanpercentile` is extremely slow

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

`numpy.nanpercentile` is extremely slow.
So, I wanted to use `cupy.nanpercentile`; but there is not `cupy.nanpercentile` implemented yet.
Do someone have solution for it?

Comment: This question needs more information to be answered well. What does your data look like? Can you filter out nulls? What specifically does slow mean? Etc.

Comment: @NickBecker My data is two dimensional array. I have to calculate nanpercentile across the column axis. nan values are randomly distributed over the array, around 10% are nan. Slow means, run time is taking few days instead of few hours.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post a small example array that captures the key attributes/nature of your data?

Answer (score 2):

I also had a problem with np.nanpercentile being very slow for my datasets. I found a wokraround that lets you use the standard np.percentile. And it can also be applied to many other libs.

This one should solve your problem. And it also works alot faster than np.nanpercentile:

```
arr = np.array([[np.nan,2,3,1,2,3],
                [np.nan,np.nan,1,3,2,1],
                [4,5,6,7,np.nan,9]])

mask = (arr >= np.nanmin(arr)).astype(int)

count = mask.sum(axis=1)
groups = np.unique(count)
groups = groups[groups > 0]

p90 = np.zeros((arr.shape[0]))
for g in range(len(groups)):
    pos = np.where (count == groups[g])
    values = arr[pos]
    values = np.nan_to_num (values, nan=(np.nanmin(arr)-1))
    values = np.sort (values, axis=1)
    values = values[:,-groups[g]:]
    p90[pos] = np.percentile (values, 90, axis=1)
```

So instead of taking the percentile with the nans, it sorts the rows by the amount of valid data, and takes the percentile of those rows separated. Then adds everything back together. This also works for 3D-arrays, just add y_pos and x_pos instead of pos. And watch out for what axis you are calculating over.

Answer (score 0):

```
def testset_gen(num):
    init=[]
    for i in range (num):
        a=random.randint(65,122) # Dummy name
        b=random.randint(1,100) # Dummy value: 11~100 and 10% of nan
        if b<11:
            b=np.nan # 10% = nan
        init.append([a,b])
    return np.array(init)
```

np_testset=testset_gen(30000000) # 468,751KB

```
def f1_np (arr, num):
    return np.percentile (arr[:,1], num)
# 55.0, 0.523902416229248 sec
```

print (f1_np(np_testset[:,1], 50))

```
def cupy_nanpercentile (arr, num):
    return len(cp.where(arr > num)[0]) / (len(arr) - cp.sum(cp.isnan(arr))) * 100
    # 55.548758317136446, 0.3640251159667969 sec
    # 43% faster
    # If You need same result, use int(). But You lose saved time.
```

print (cupy_nanpercentile(cp_testset[:,1], 50))

I can't imagine How test result takes few days. With my computer, It seems 1 Trillion line of data or more. Because of this, I can't reproduce same problem due to lack of resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation with numba. After it's been compiled it is more than 7x faster than the numpy version.

Right now it is set up to take the percentile along the first axis, however it could be changed easily.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def nan_percentile_axis0(arr, percentiles):
    """Faster implementation of np.nanpercentile
    
    This implementation always takes the percentile along axis 0.
    Uses numba to speed up the calculation by more than 7x.

    Function is equivalent to np.nanpercentile(arr, <percentiles>, axis=0)

    Params:
        arr (np.array): Array to calculate percentiles for
        percentiles (np.array): 1D array of percentiles to calculate

    Returns:
        (np.array) Array with first dimension corresponding to
            values as passed in percentiles

    """
    shape = arr.shape
    arr = arr.reshape((arr.shape[0], -1))
    out = np.empty((len(percentiles), arr.shape[1]))
    for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
        out[:,i] = np.nanpercentile(arr[:,i], percentiles)
    shape = (out.shape[0], *shape[1:])
    return out.reshape(shape)
```